# Bash Script get cpu(s) from lscpu

Tags: linux

I run lscpu to get the number of cpu(s)

```
lscpu | grep -i "Model name:" | cut -d':' -f2- -
```

Result:
CPU(s):              2
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0,1

How do get only the CPU(s) number and drop all the other info collected? I just need to get the number of cpus and nothing more.

Thank you learning Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of cores:
`lscpu | egrep "^CPU\(s\):" | sed -e "s/[^0-9]//g"`

...the number of CPUs:
`lscpu | egrep "^Socket\(s\):" | sed -e "s/[^0-9]//g"`

...and to list the cpu numbers:
`lscpu -p=cpu`

See `man lscpu`.

Some explanation:
`egrep` uses regular expressions to extract a line. The carret symbol matches the beginning of the line, the backslash is to escape the bracket sign, means the line should start with the given text and the brackets are taken as they are with no further meaning.
`sed` extracts only the number characters of the line using:
`s`...
as the replace command, 
`[^0-9]`...
matches all non-numerical characters and replaces them with nothing in every occurrence (by using `g`). The slashes are to separate the four parts: Replace/What to replace/with what/globally

There are at least million ways to achieve what you ask. The given one is probably not the best, but you get an idea.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I voted for you it says my vote is counted but not public until I get more rep.  Thank you again